# Using gsub or similar function to replace one character variable with part of another character variable

Tags: r, string, gsub

I hope this is an easy question.

I have two variables, I want to take out the string of one variable from another, basically to get whatever else is left in 2nd variable

```
variable1='test'
variable2='test2'
wantedresult='2'

newdf=as.data.frame(cbind(variable1,variable2,wantedresult))
```

If gsub worked with 2 columns, I would use this, but the first argument has to be a string and not a variable

```
gsub(newdf$variable2,'',newdf$variable1)
```

Is there another way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: `newdf <- data.frame(variable1='test', variable2='test2');
newdf$wanted <- with(newdf, gsub(variable1, '', variable2, fixed = TRUE));
newdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple rows, you have to use a technique that can vectorize the operation. Here is an example using `mapply`.

```
# Create example data frame
variable1 <- c('test', 'bus')
variable2 <- c('test2', 'bus3')
wantedresult <- c('2', '3')

newdf <- data.frame(variable1, variable2, wantedresult, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
newdf
#   variable1 variable2 wantedresult
# 1      test     test2            2
# 2       bus      bus3            3

# Apply the gsub function using mapply
mapply(gsub, pattern = newdf$variable1, replacement = "", x = newdf$variable2)
# test  bus 
# "2"  "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
# data
variable1 <- 'test'
variable2 <- 'test2'
newdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(variable1,variable2))
# solution
library(data.table)
setDT(newdf)[, wantedresult := gsub(variable1, '', variable2, fixed = TRUE)]
newdf # output
  variable1 variable2 wantedresult
1:      test     test2            2
```